# Argument parser from a Pydantic model

Tags: python, argparse, pydantic

How do I create an argument parser (`argparse.ArgumentParser`) from a Pydantic model?

I have a Pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    color: str = Field(default="red", description="Color of the item")
```

And I want to create an instance of `MyItem` using command line:

```
python myscript.py --name Jack --age 10 --color blue
```

This should yield to:

```
item = MyItem(name="Jack", age=10, color="blue")
... # Process the item
```

I would not like to hard-code the command-line arguments and I would like to create the command-line arguments dynamically from the Pydantic model.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an answer myself. Just:

1. create an argument parser,
2. turn the fields of the model as arguments of the parser,
3. parse the command-line arguments,
4. turn the arguments as dict and pass them to the model and
5. process the instance of the model

```
import argparse
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    color: str = Field(default="red", description="Color of the item")

def add_model(parser, model):
    "Add Pydantic model to an ArgumentParser"
    fields = model.__fields__
    for name, field in fields.items():
        parser.add_argument(
            f"--{name}", 
            dest=name, 
            type=field.type_, 
            default=field.default,
            help=field.field_info.description,
        )

# 1. Create and parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# 2. Turn the fields of the model as arguments of the parser
add_model(parser, MyItem)

# 3. Parse the command-line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# 4. Turn the arguments as dict and pass them to the model
item = MyItem(**vars(args))

# 5. Do whatever
print(repr(item))
...
```

You may also add subparsers if you wish to add more functionality to the parser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [pydantic-argparse](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-argparse/), that might just do what you need, without additional boilerplate code.

Here is an example from its docs

```
import pydantic
import pydantic_argparse


class Arguments(pydantic.BaseModel):
    # Required Args
    string: str = pydantic.Field(description="a required string")
    integer: int = pydantic.Field(description="a required integer")
    flag: bool = pydantic.Field(description="a required flag")

    # Optional Args
    second_flag: bool = pydantic.Field(False, description="an optional flag")
    third_flag: bool = pydantic.Field(True, description="an optional flag")


def main() -> None:
    # Create Parser and Parse Args
    parser = pydantic_argparse.ArgumentParser(
        model=Arguments,
        prog="Example Program",
        description="Example Description",
        version="0.0.1",
        epilog="Example Epilog",
    )
    args = parser.parse_typed_args()

    # Print Args
    print(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Use [`tap.tapify`](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser?tab=readme-ov-file#pydantic) in the package `typed-argument-parser`.

Here's a [WIP](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser/issues/125) answer for [`typed-argument-parser`](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser).

```py
from typing import Type

from tap import Tap
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


def _tap_from_pydantic_model(model: Type[BaseModel]) -> Type[Tap]:
    class ArgParser(Tap):
        def configure(self):
            for name, field in model.model_fields.items():
                self._annotations[name] = field.annotation
                self.class_variables[name] = {"comment": field.description or ""}
                # The help string will be nicely constructed in _add_argument
                if field.is_required():
                    kwargs = {}
                else:
                    kwargs = dict(required=False, default=field.default)
                self.add_argument(f"--{name}", **kwargs)

    return ArgParser


class Model(BaseModel):
    """
    My Pydantic Model which contains script args.
    """

    arg_str: str = Field(description="hello")
    arg_bool: bool = Field(default=True, description=None)
    arg_list: list[str] | None = Field(default=None, description="optional list")


def main(model: Model) -> None:
    print("Parsed args into Model:")
    print(model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ModelTap = _tap_from_pydantic_model(Model)
    args = ModelTap(description="Script description").parse_args()
    model = Model(**args.as_dict())
    main(model)
```

Help message:

```
$ python demo.py -h
usage: demo.py --arg_str ARG_STR [--arg_bool] [--arg_list [ARG_LIST ...]] [-h]

Script description

options:
  --arg_str ARG_STR     (str, required) hello
  --arg_bool            (bool, default=True)
  --arg_list [ARG_LIST ...]
                        (list[str] | None, default=None) optional list
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Example usage:

```
$ python demo.py \
--arg_str test \
--arg_list x y z \
--arg_bool
Parsed args into Model:
arg_str='test' arg_bool=False arg_list=['x', 'y', 'z']
```